# Thread safe wrapper around std::queue doesn't build if storing unique_ptr, but std::queue works

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a supposed thread safe blocking queue implementation which is supposed to be a wrapper around std::queue
Below is its implementation:

```
template <typename _Tp>
class SharedQueue
{
  public:
    explicit SharedQueue(bool isBlocking = true) : isBlocking_(isBlocking) {}

    virtual ~SharedQueue() {}

    virtual const _Tp& front()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

        // if this is a blocking queue, wait to be notified when when a new object is added
        if (isBlocking_)
        {
            while (queue_.empty())
            {
                cv_.wait(mlock);
            }
        }

        return queue_.front();
    }

    virtual bool empty() const
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

        return queue_.empty();
    }

    virtual size_t size() const
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

        return queue_.size();
    }

    virtual void push(const _Tp& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

        queue_.push(value);

        if (isBlocking_)
        {
            if (queue_.size() == 1)
            {
                cv_.notify_all();
            }
        }
    }

    virtual void push(_Tp&& value)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

            queue_.push(std::move(value));

            if (isBlocking_)
            {
                if (queue_.size() == 1)
                {
                    cv_.notify_all();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    template <typename... _Args>
    void emplace(_Args&&... __args)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

            queue_.emplace(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);

            if (isBlocking_)
            {
                if (queue_.size() == 1)
                {
                    cv_.notify_all();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    virtual void pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

        if (!queue_.empty())
        {
            queue_.pop();
        }
    }

  private:
    bool isBlocking_;

    mutable std::mutex mtx_;

    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;

    std::queue<_Tp> queue_;
};
```

I want to be be able to place unique_ptr's on this queue and I understand that I'd have to call std::move on the unique_ptr when pushing it on the queue from a client application.
Here's my problem...
In my main, when I create a std::queue as follows, my program compiles just fine

```
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<int32_t>> q1;
```

However, when I create an instance of my SharedQueue as below, the program does not compile.

```
SharedQueue<std::unique_ptr<int32_t>> q2;
```

I get an error telling me the copy constructor was deleted in the unique_ptr class, which is understandable. I guess I'm just wondering what std::queue does that the code can compile while my code 'appears' to be a wrapper around the std::queue and implements the operations similarly.

EDIT:
I can get the SharedQueue to compile if I replace

```
queue_.push(value);
```

with

```
queue_.push(std::forward<_Tp>(const_cast<_Tp&>(value)));
```

Inside the push method that takes in an lvalue reference.

Comment: Did you try to push any values onto `q1`?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, when I do it properly with a std::move I don't get compilation errors, but when I try to call push without it, I get an error telling my the copy ctor was deleted in the std::unique_ptr class

Comment: Exactly. See where your `SharedQueue` is pushing onto the queue without using `std::move()`?

Comment: @shawn I want a more generic queue where I don't have to call move inside SharedQueue and that ought to be left up to the client, especially if it's in the lvalue ref push call

Comment: Then don't use it with a non-copyable type?

Comment: I still don't get why std::queue compiles and the SharedQueue does not.

Comment: @tree Because `std::queue` uses template/SFINAE magic with `std::enable_if` to include functions that copy only if the class is copyable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see that a bunch of enable_if calls in the header. I'll have to investigate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There's no need for template magic in the `std::queue` case. The compiler will only throw an error of "using deleted copy constructor" is you try to instance it in your code. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ydnfj)

Comment: @JoelFilho That's pretty much the basis of my question because I'm not really calling the push method that will try to copy a unique ptr

Comment: That comment was actually about @DavidSchwartz "it's template magic". Because, in this instance, [there's none](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/queue#L305).

Comment: Why do you make all those member functions `virtual`?

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm inheriting from an interface class which I didn't show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem relies in:

```cpp
    virtual void push(const _Tp& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);
        queue_.push(value);
     [...]
```

If you remove the `virtual` keyword, it'll compile fine, and it'll fall back to the `std::queue` case: It'll only emit an error if you use the function.

I assume that using `virtual` emits the error because, since it requires the compiler to generate a vtable, the function code needs to be generated and pointed to.

A way to keep it virtual and still work would probably be by using SFINAE with `std::is_copy_constructible` and `std::is_move_constructible` specializations of a class inheriting from your base, where the `push` member function is pure virtual.

---

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/TQwBSG)'s a (Bad. Don't do OO C++ like that. Really) sample implementation of that idea. Notice that, the same way you can't just "not call in code" the virtual `push`, you can't just delete the push on the specialization and must do something on runtime. In this example, an exception is thrown.

There are better ways to do that. I'm considering you really need those member functions to be virtual. Otherwise, your problem would be solved by just removing the keyword.

One would be making full specializations of your SharedQueue class, putting the `push` overloads where you need them, but reusing the rest of the code in composition way, instead of by inheritance.

Another one would be making the same thing on a `queue` wrapper, which would be smaller and more readable, then using it in your current code ([Example](https://godbolt.org/z/pQIuaN), again, not good, but illustrates the point).

The elegant, C++17-or-newer way, is just using `if constexpr`:

```cpp
virtual void push(const _Tp& value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mtx_);

    if constexpr(std::is_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>){
      queue_.push(value);
    } else{
      throw std::invalid_argument("The type _Tp can't be copy constructed");
    }

    if (isBlocking_) {
      if (queue_.size() == 1) {
        cv_.notify_all();
      }
    }
  }
```